# How do I publish a grails 3 plugin to my local nexus repo?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-3.0

Running `grails publish-plugin` doesn't seem to do anything, and the only documentation I could find was about publishing to bintray.

[edit:]

I can publish the plugin via `gradle publish`, but wondered if there was a grails-y way to do it, and wonder what `grails publish-plugin` actually does :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out with help from [Ryan Vanderwerf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3638568/ryan-v) at http://rvanderwerf.blogspot.com/2015/07/how-to-publish-grails-3-plugin.html who writes that there are a bunch of spring-boot dependencies that don't have versions in them and that causes gradle to freak out. To workaround it, strip out all dependencies in the pom that doesn't have versions:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJar(MavenPublication) {
            pom.withXml {
                def pomNode = asNode()
                pomNode.dependencyManagement.replaceNode {}

                // simply remove dependencies without a version
                // version-less dependencies are handled with dependencyManagement
                // see https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin/issues/8 for more complete solutions
                pomNode.dependencies.dependency.findAll {
                    it.version.text().isEmpty()
                }.each {
                    it.replaceNode {}
                }
            }
            from components.java
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            credentials {
                username "username"
                password "password"
            }
            url "http://localhost/repo"
        }
    }
}
```

then you can use `grails publish-plugin` or `gradle publish` to publish your plugin

related SO question: [Grails 3 - How to publish to Artifactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30956826/grails-3-how-to-publish-to-artifactory)

Comment: the solution works for me. At result it show 403 error. But in artifactory all files are presented

Answer (score 1):

In Grails 3.0.11, I use the gradle target *publishToMavenLocal* for my local development.  There is also another target *publishMavenPublicationToMavenRepository*.  This seems to come from the gradle plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
```

Seems to be in the standard plugin build.gradle.

(Edit: Adding notes on using local maven).

After re-reading your question and comment below, I don't think that is what you are looking for.  It sounds like you want a normal publish to a repository on your system.  `publishMavenPublicationToMavenRepository` may handle that.  What I described above is using the local Maven cache to hold a snapshot of a plugin that you can use on your machine in an application.

This works for me when developing a plugin used in my application.

I did not create a local repository.  The gradle plugin above (`maven-publish`) has a task `publishToMavenLocal` that will publish the Grails plugin to the local maven cache for local development.

It stores the plugin's .zip file in the .m2 cache directory:

```
C:\Users\xyz\.m2\repository\org\whatever\plugins\pluginName\0.3-SNAPSHOT
```

Then, you can use the plugin in a Grails application on your machine.

Answer (score -3):

In grails 2.x 
BuildConfig.groovy

```
grails.project.dependency.distribution = {
    remoteRepository(id: '<repo name>',    url: '<url to your nexus repo>')
}

Then:

grails clean

grails compile 

grails maven-deploy --repository=repo name
```

In grails 3.x+:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        ...
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
    }
}
publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            credentials {
                username "xyz"
                password "xyz"
            }
            url "http://example.com/nexus/content/repositories/nfb"
        }
    }
}
```

and finally

gradle publish

Comment: grails 3 does not have a BuildConfig.groovy