# Unable to plublish grails 3 plugin to local maven repo

Tags: maven, grails, gradle

I am trying to publish a plugin on a local maven repo but unable to do so, I am getting following error when I execute "**gradle publish**" command from the project folder.

```
:generatePomFileForMavenJarPublication
:compileAstJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileAstGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:processAstResources UP-TO-DATE
:astClasses UP-TO-DATE
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:configScript UP-TO-DATE
:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:copyAstClasses UP-TO-DATE
:copyCommands UP-TO-DATE
:copyTemplates UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar UP-TO-DATE
:publishMavenJarPublicationToMavenRepository FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':publishMavenJarPublicationToMavenRepository'.
> Failed to publish publication 'mavenJar' to repository 'maven'
   > org.codehaus.plexus.PlexusContainerException: Cycle detected in component graph in the system: 

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.403 secs
```

In my build.gradle I have following block:

```
publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            credentials {
                username 'USERNAME'
                password= 'PASS'
            }
            url "MAVEN HOST/artifactory"
        }
    }
}
```

I even tried the solution mentioned [How do I publish a grails 3 plugin to my local nexus repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34756023/how-do-i-publish-a-grails-3-plugin-to-my-local-nexus-repo) but that also didn't work for me.

With stacktrace option enable, I get the following log:

```
:generatePomFileForMavenPublication
:compileAstJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileAstGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:processAstResources UP-TO-DATE
:astClasses UP-TO-DATE
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:configScript UP-TO-DATE
:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:copyAstClasses UP-TO-DATE
:copyCommands UP-TO-DATE
:copyTemplates UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar UP-TO-DATE
:groovydoc UP-TO-DATE
:javadoc UP-TO-DATE
:javadocJar UP-TO-DATE
:sourcesJar UP-TO-DATE
:publishMavenPublicationToMavenRepository FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':publishMavenPublicationToMavenRepository'.
> Failed to publish publication 'maven' to repository 'maven'
   > org.codehaus.plexus.PlexusContainerException: Cycle detected in component graph in the system: 

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':publishMavenPublicationToMavenRepository'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:154)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:151)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:170)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.PublishException: Failed to publish publication 'maven' to repository 'maven'
    at org.gradle.api.publish.internal.PublishOperation.run(PublishOperation.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.tasks.PublishToMavenRepository.doPublish(PublishToMavenRepository.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.tasks.PublishToMavenRepository.publish(PublishToMavenRepository.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:227)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:220)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:209)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:585)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:568)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: org.codehaus.plexus.PlexusContainerException: Cycle detected in component graph in the system: 
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:45)
    at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.action.AbstractMavenPublishAction.newPlexusContainer(AbstractMavenPublishAction.java:117)
    at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.action.AbstractMavenPublishAction.<init>(AbstractMavenPublishAction.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.action.MavenDeployAction.<init>(MavenDeployAction.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.publisher.MavenRemotePublisher$GradleWagonMavenDeployAction.<init>(MavenRemotePublisher.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.publisher.MavenRemotePublisher.createDeployTask(MavenRemotePublisher.java:47)
    at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.publisher.AbstractMavenPublisher.publish(AbstractMavenPublisher.java:45)
    at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.publisher.StaticLockingMavenPublisher.publish(StaticLockingMavenPublisher.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.publisher.ValidatingMavenPublisher.publish(ValidatingMavenPublisher.java:48)
    at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.tasks.PublishToMavenRepository$1.publish(PublishToMavenRepository.java:83)
    at org.gradle.api.publish.internal.PublishOperation.run(PublishOperation.java:36)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.PlexusContainerException: Cycle detected in component graph in the system: 
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.initialize(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:624)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.construct(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:281)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init>(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:172)
    at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.action.AbstractMavenPublishAction.newPlexusContainer(AbstractMavenPublishAction.java:115)
    ... 76 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.component.composition.CycleDetectedInComponentGraphException: Cyclic requirement detected
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.composition.DefaultCompositionResolver.addComponentDescriptor(DefaultCompositionResolver.java:65)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.DefaultComponentRepository.addComponentDescriptor(DefaultComponentRepository.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultComponentRegistry.addComponentDescriptor(DefaultComponentRegistry.java:126)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.addComponentDescriptor(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:514)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.discoverComponents(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:969)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.discoverComponents(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:941)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.initialize(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:560)
    ... 79 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.util.dag.CycleDetectedException: Edge between 'Vertex{label='org.apache.maven.plugin.MavenPluginManager:default'}' and 'Vertex{label='org.apache.maven.plugin.version.PluginVersionResolver:default'}' introduces to cycle in the graph org.apache.maven.plugin.version.PluginVersionResolver:default --> org.apache.maven.plugin.MavenPluginManager:default --> org.apache.maven.plugin.version.PluginVersionResolver:default
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.dag.DAG.addEdge(DAG.java:143)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.dag.DAG.addEdge(DAG.java:123)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.composition.DefaultCompositionResolver.addComponentDescriptor(DefaultCompositionResolver.java:60)
    ... 85 more


BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: What happens when you run with --stacktrace? Could you share the output, please?

Comment: @viniciusartur updated the post with the log, thanks.

Comment: what version of gradle are you using?

Comment: gradleWrapperVersion=3.4.1

Comment: I suggest you trying a different version of gradle or checking if all the dependencies of your plugin have versions.